# Induction proof combination

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

How would you solve the proof of the sum of $kC(n,k) = n2^{n-1}$ by induction?
Thanks for your help.

It is for an exam for a discrete math class.

Comment: what work have you done so far?

Comment: @David solve at least the base case.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this known formula $2^n$ = sum of C(n,k) | k=0 to k=n .

you should prove that sum of $kC(n,k) = n2^{n-1}/(n-k+1)$

not $kC(n,k) = n2^{n-1}$ because it is false.